# php join two elements of array

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>prophet,"family"=>muhammad);
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>ali);
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>hossein);
```

I want merge only `name` and `family` to `fullName`?

I want like this

```
$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>prophet,"family"=>muhammad,"fullName"=>"prophet muhammad");
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>ali,"fullName"=>"imam ali");
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>hossein,"fullName"=>"imam hossein");
```

I can do with this code

```
$count=0;
foreach($MyArray as $R)
{            
    $result[$count++]=array("name"=>$R["name"],"family"=>$R["family"],"fullName"=>$R["name"]." ".$R["family"]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/kOl5zh)

there is better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map()` in your code like this:

```
<?php

$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=> "prophet", "family"=> "muhammad");
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=> "imam", "family"=> "ali");
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=> "imam", "family"=> "hossein");

$array = array_map(function($n) {$n['fullName'] = $n['name'] . ' ' . $n['family']; return $n;}, $MyArray);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => prophet
            [family] => muhammad
            [fullName] => prophet muhammad
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => imam
            [family] => ali
            [fullName] => imam ali
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => imam
            [family] => hossein
            [fullName] => imam hossein
        )

)
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/array_map

Answer (score 4):

Just assign a new key pair value inside your current array structure. A simple foreach should suffice:

```
$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>"prophet","family"=>"muhammad");
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>"imam","family"=>"ali");
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>"imam","family"=>"hossein");

foreach($MyArray as &$arr) {
                  // ^ reference
    $arr['fullName'] = "{$arr['name']} {$arr['family']}";
    //   ^ new key       ^ new value assignment
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D0SKRN)

Answer (score 2):

```
$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>prophet,"family"=>muhammad);
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>ali);
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>hossein);
$count = count($MyArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $MyArray[$i]['fullName'] = $MyArray[$i]['name'] . ' ' . $MyArray[$i]['family'];
}
print_r($MyArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the foreach loop. Here is an example.

```
$MyArray[0]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>prophet,"family"=>muhammad);
$MyArray[1]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>ali);
$MyArray[2]=Array("id"=>1,"name"=>imam,"family"=>hossein);

foreach($MyArray as $key=>$myarray){
     $MyArray[$key]["fullName"] = $myarray["name"]." ".$myarray["family"];
}
```